# HTMLAgility:Replace two nodes with a new element

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I am looping through a nodes collection. I have to replace the current node and sibling of the current node with a new element.

I have written the below code for doing that:

```
private void modifyNodes(IEnumerable<HtmlNode> selectedNodes)
{
            foreach (var node in selectedNodes)
            {           

                node.NextSibling.SetAttributeValue("style", "font-weight:bold;padding:2px 2px;");             
                node.SetAttributeValue("style", "float:right;");                

                var parentNode = node.ParentNode;

                var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                var newElement = doc.CreateElement("table");
                newElement.SetAttributeValue("style", "background-color:#e4ecf8;width:100%");
                var sectionRow = doc.CreateElement("tr");
                var headerColumn = doc.CreateElement("td");
                headerColumn.AppendChild(node.NextSibling);
                var weightColumn = doc.CreateElement("td");
                weightColumn.AppendChild(node);
                sectionRow.AppendChild(headerColumn);
                sectionRow.AppendChild(weightColumn);
                newElement.AppendChild(sectionRow);

                element.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
                parentNode.ReplaceChild(newElement, node.NextSibling);

            }
}
```

This is adding the new element and removing the passed node. But it's failing to remove the next sibling of the node. What am I doing wrong here.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You're *explicitly* replaced `node.NextSibling` with the `newElement`, as you said that the new element was added. The problem may be in the type of the next sibling. Most probably, this is a text node (very often those `\r\n` which divide the HTML nodes).

So it seems, that your new node just replaced the text node, and the result is a bit unexpected. So if this is a really an issue, you could do a workaround like this:

```
// next sibling
var next = node.NextSibling;
// get the first non-text node
while (next != null && next is HtmlTextNode)
    next = next.NextSibling;

var newNode = doc.CreateElement(...);
// replace the current node with the new one
current.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode, current);
// remove the next node if it was found
if (next != null)
    next.Remove();
```

Comment: I have verified the HTML the two nodes will always be of type div. is there way by which I can get two adjacent nodes and replace it at one with the new node?

Comment: @San: I think no. Can you just remove the next sibling by using `next.Remove()`? Does it remove the node?